# Magento 2 frontend route only allow POST method

Tags: magento2, magento-2.2.5, routing, http-request, post-data

I'm using magento 2.2.5 and created a frontend route like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="spin" frontName="spin">
            <module name="Neverending_Story" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

How can i allow only POST method request that can access this route ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Magento request object has a function

`$this->getRequest()->getMethod()` which provide the request method name on request object. So using this `getMethod()`,you can prevent your route from all other request accept POST..

Create an observer on event

> `controller_action_predispatch_spin`

And on that observer if you will found that the request method  `$observer->getEvent()->getRequest()->getMethod()` ,then dis-allow the  all pages of this routes `<route id="spin" frontName="spin">`

**Call observer from events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
     <event name="controller_action_predispatch_spin">
        <observer instance="StackExchange\Magento\Observer\Frontend\CheckAndPrevent" 
                  name="prevent_all_method"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

**Observer code:**

```
<?php


namespace StackExchange\Magento\Observer\Frontend;


class CheckAndPrevent implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{



    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
       //$eventParameters = ['controller_action' => $this, 'request' => $request];
        $request = $observer->getEvent()->getRequest();
        $requestMethod = strtolower($request->getMethod());

        if($requestMethod !== 'put'){

           // echo $requestMethod;
            // Throw an exception for prevent the accesss
            throw new \Exception("Cannot access."); 


        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use M 2.3 then easily use that. You controller should implements the following interface:

> Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpPostActionInterface

[Check contact module post action how it's use](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3/app/code/Magento/Contact/Controller/Index/Post.php#L21)

Comment: im using magento 2.2.5

Answer (score 1):

If you are to use this route for an API like endpoint, I would suggest using [**webapi.xml configuration options**](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/service-contracts/service-to-web-service.html#configuration-options) instead. Register the route as a REST API endpoint.

You can do it like below:

> webapi.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Webapi:etc/webapi.xsd">
    <route method="POST" url="/V1/spin">
        <service class="YourVendor\YourModule\Controller\Index\Index" method="execute"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="anonymous"/>
        </resources>
    </route>
</routes>
```

Then your POST Endpoint: **yourdomain.com/rest/V1/spin**

This might not be the appropriate solution but I think this will do the work.

Answer (score 1):

In **Magento < 2.3** versions, I don't think there is a way to set this up in the route definition level. [**As Sohel explained in his answer**](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/282035/3535), it is possible to ensure this in **Magento >= 2.3** in the controller level.

However, you can make sure whether the method is POST or not by the request object. You can check this in the `execute()` method as shown below:

```
public function execute()
{
    $isPostRequest = !empty($this->getRequest()->getPostValue());

    if (!$isPostRequest) {
        // Not a POST request; logic to show some error
    }

    // Do relevant stuff here...
}
```